# Node.js use mssql for accessing database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, meteor

I'm making the Meteor.js app and I have to get data from mssql database. I use Meteor 1.8 and a npm package - mssql(version 5.1.0). That's my code:

```
const sql = require('mssql')

const config = {something}

export default function fetch(query) {
    const config = {something}

    sql.connect(config, err => {

        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
        }

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request()

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query(query, (err, recordset) => {

            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                return
            }

            return recordset
        })
    })
}
```

And I have such error

> TypeError: sql.connect is not a function

I don't know what's going on, I tried to do it in many ways and I failed. When I use **ConnectionPool** I see an error saying that ConnectionPool is not a constructor.
What is the proper way to do this?

In my config file I have: user, password, server, database, port.

Comment: You're' mixing your metaphors there. You're using `require`, but in an ESM module rather than a CommonJS one. You want to use one or the other.

Comment: That code won't run in Node.js. Node.js complains about the fact that you're mixing your module systems (per the above). How are you running it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, can I import mssql?

Comment: You can with Node.js currently-experimental ESM module support, yes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in a meteor in publication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be because you're mixing your module systems, you're using `require` (which is CommonJS-like) but in something that's apparently an ECMAScript module (ESM) (from the `export default ...`). Node.js itself won't let you do that, but if you're using some kind of bundler or transpiler, perhaps it might...

Changing your `require` to:

```
import sql from "mssql";
```

...and making sure Node.js is using ESM¹, I don't get any error with `sql.connect` not being a function.

---

¹ In my case, since I'm using Node.js v12, I do that by having `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` and running it via `node --experimental-modules filename.js`, more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Comment: Belatedly remembering this is Meteor, no idea how that may affect the above.

Comment: I know and I have no idea how to use those flags. Can I just use require, and modules.exports and in the file I  need to use that function, can I use import {fetch} from 'sth'?

Comment: @Karol - I'd think so, yes. :-)

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot, but I have a question, it says that I cannot connect to the database, I found a post saying that I should enable TCP connection, but how should I do it on ubuntu?

Comment: @Karol - I'm afraid it's been a while, probably best to ask on https://superuser.com or https://askubuntu.com/. It's the `ufw` utility IIRC (or at least, it was when I last looked at this on Ubuntu).